# Does anyone know if Heroku is still with Facebook?

Tags: facebook, heroku

I created an facebook app and now there is no "host your app in Heroku" I wanted check the default python application for the facebook app.

So Im not sure if now I'm not able to create more apps in heroku or heroku is no longer with facebook or maybe it is a bug.

Does someone know what is happening here ?

Thank you

Comment: I have created a new php app yesterday and hosted it on heroku.

Comment: Interesting, so it could be that I created a lot of facebook apps already ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The formal Facebook integration is [no longer available](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-your-facebook-app-as-a-canvas-page).

However, independent of whether or not the button to create a Heroku app is on Facebook or not, [you can always create an app on Heroku that integrates with Facebook](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook). You'll just have to manually perform the administrative and configuration steps that were previously automated.

You mentioned wanting the default Python app? You can find the various Heroku/Facebook app templates in GitHub:

- [Python Facebook app](https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-python)
- [Ruby Facebook app](https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-ruby)
- [PHP Facebook app](https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-php)
- [Node.js Facebook app](https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs)

Comment: I guess your questions is related to "how to host a facebook iframe app" with ssl? I didn't want to mess around setting up a host with ssl, so i ended up creating a "blank app" at www.backlift.com. Then I just added the html/css in the connected dropbox-folder, and added the backlift-url in the app-URL-part when you create a facebook iframe app (on developer.facebook.com). Hopefully someone finds this info useful.